# Play next button iframe src when the other one is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my code : `codepen.io/yasiin-bronce/pen/oNzezJO`

i need to play other next video after preview one finishes

can i get help pls?

note: click in the list button to get video load

Comment: Hey, please add some code next to your codepen as SO requires. also, your link is broken and could discourage users from helping you.

Comment: pls can you tell me how , cause i dont know how to use stackoverflow